# $watch not updating scope variable

Tags: angularjs, watch

First I want to say that I am a complete beginner in AngularJS and just attempting to understand the basic concepts. I have a background in Java and PHP.

I am building a part of a website. Right now the angular app only consists of opening and closing 2 drop down menus registrationDropDown and loginDropDown. I want them to work so that only one can be open at a time ie. if I open one, and the other is already open, the older one is forced to close.

I have a service to manage the variables that determine whether the drop downs should be open or closed and 2 controllers, one for login and one for registration, both include $watch for the respective variables.

THE PROBLEM
I want the app to work so that only one of the drop downs can be open at one time.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/F5p6m/3/

```
    angular.module("ftApp", [])
    .factory('dropDownService', function () {
    var loginDropDownStatus = false;
    var registrationDropDownStatus = false;

    return {
        getLoginDropDownStatus: function () {
            return loginDropDownStatus;
        },
        showLoginDropDown: function () {
            console.log("showing login drop down");
            registrationDropDownStatus = false;
            loginDropDownStatus = true;
            console.log("loginDropDownStatus" + loginDropDownStatus + "registrationDropDownStatus" + registrationDropDownStatus);
        },
        hideLoginDropDown: function () {
            console.log("hiding login drop down");
            loginDropDownStatus = false;
            console.log("loginDropDownStatus" + loginDropDownStatus);

        },
        getRegistrationDropDownStatus: function () {
            return registrationDropDownStatus;
        },
        showRegistrationDropDown: function () {
            console.log("showing registration drop down");
            registrationDropDownStatus = true;
            loginDropDownStatus = false;
            console.log("registrationDropDownStatus" + registrationDropDownStatus);
        },
        hideRegistrationDropDown: function () {
            console.log("hiding registration drop down");
            registrationDropDownStatus = false;
            console.log("registrationDropDownStatus" + registrationDropDownStatus);
        }
    };

}) .controller("LoginDropDownController", function ($scope, dropDownService) {
        $scope.loginDropDownStatus = dropDownService.getLoginDropDownStatus();

        $scope.$watchCollection('loginDropDownStatus', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("watcher is working");
            console.log("value is " + newValue + oldValue);

            console.log("LOGIN new value is " + newValue);
            $scope.loginDropDownStatus = newValue;
        });

        $scope.toggleDropDown = function () {

            if ( $scope.loginDropDownStatus == false ) {
                dropDownService.showLoginDropDown();
                dropDownService.hideRegistrationDropDown();
                $scope.loginDropDownStatus = true;
            } else if ( $scope.loginDropDownStatus == true ) {
                dropDownService.hideLoginDropDown();
                $scope.loginDropDownStatus = false;
            }
        };

    })

        .controller("RegistrationDropDownController", function ($scope, dropDownService) {

        $scope.registrationDropDownStatus = dropDownService.getRegistrationDropDownStatus();

        $scope.$watch('registrationDropDownStatus', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("watcher is working");
            console.log("value is " + newValue + oldValue);

            console.log("new value is " + newValue);
            $scope.registrationDropDownStatus = newValue;
        });

        $scope.toggleDropDown = function () {

            if ( $scope.registrationDropDownStatus == false ) {
                dropDownService.showRegistrationDropDown();
                dropDownService.hideLoginDropDown();
                $scope.registrationDropDownStatus = true;
            } else if ( $scope.registrationDropDownStatus == true ) {
                dropDownService.hideRegistrationDropDown();
                $scope.registrationDropDownStatus = false;
            }
        };

        })
```

Comment: Isolate the problem and make a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F5p6m/3/

Comment: How is that isolating the problem?

Comment: I cannot take anything off from there aside from console logging can I? Otherwise it will not work anymore.

But in words I can say the problem is simple: I want to do so that only one of those drop downs would be open at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Here is probably the shortest option:

```
angular.module("ftApp", [])
    .controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = function(menu){
         $scope.active = $scope.active === menu ? null : menu;
    }
})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/56yzb/)

One controller, no service.

---

Previous Answer:

I think you have quite a bit of code to get something very simple done. Here is my solution:

```
angular.module("ftApp", [])
    .service('dropDownService', function () {        
        this.active = null;
        this.toggle = function(menu){
            this.active = this.active === menu ? null : menu;
        }
})

    .controller("LoginDropDownController", function ($scope, dropDownService) {
    $scope.status = dropDownService;
    $scope.toggleDropDown = function () {
        dropDownService.toggle("login");
    };

})

    .controller("RegistrationDropDownController", function ($scope, dropDownService) {
    $scope.status = dropDownService;
    $scope.toggleDropDown = function () {
        dropDownService.toggle("reg");
    };

})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/F5p6m/7/)

You can make it even shorter by only using one controller. You wouldn't even need the service then.

Comment: Made this the accepted answer as it seems like the best practice. I ended up using a single controller as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. All you need your service to hold is a property indicating which dorpdown should be active.

Then you can change that property's value from the controller and check the value in the view to determine if a dropdown should be shown or hidden.

Something like this:

```
<!-- In the VIEW -->
<li ng-controller="XyzController">
    <a ng-click="toggleDropdown()">Xyz</a>
    <div ng-show="isActive()">Dropdown</div>
</li>

/* In the SERVICE */
.factory('DropdownService', function () {
    return {
        activeDropDown: null
    };
})

/* In the CONTROLLER */
controller("XyzDropdownController", function ($scope, DropdownService) {
    var dropdownName = 'xyz';
    var dds = DropdownService;
    $scope.isActive = function () {
        return dropdownName === dds.activeDropdown;
    };
    $scope.toggleDropdown = function () {
        dds.activeDropdown = (dds.activeDropdown === dropdownName) ?
                null :
                dropdownName;
    };
})
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/XhfWL/)**.

---

<sub>Based on what exactly you are doing, there might be other approaches possible/preferrable:

E.g. you could use just on controller to control all dropdowns
or you could use two instances of the same controller to control each dropdown.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

See my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5p6m/5/). I simplified the code and removed the service. Because you just used two variables to control visibility, you don't need a service nor `$watch`. You need to keep variables in the `$rootScope`, otherwise changes in a controller is not visible to another controller due to isolated scopes.

```
angular.module("ftApp", [])
    .controller("LoginDropDownController", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.loginDropDownStatus = false;
    $scope.toggleDropDown = function () {
        if ($rootScope.loginDropDownStatus == false) {
            $rootScope.registrationDropDownStatus = false;
            $rootScope.loginDropDownStatus = true;
        } else if ($rootScope.loginDropDownStatus == true) {
            $rootScope.loginDropDownStatus = false;
        }
    };
}).controller("RegistrationDropDownController", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.registrationDropDownStatus = false;
    $scope.toggleDropDown = function () {

        if ($rootScope.registrationDropDownStatus === false) {
            $rootScope.loginDropDownStatus = false;
            $rootScope.registrationDropDownStatus = true;
        } else if ($scope.registrationDropDownStatus === true) {
            $rootScope.registrationDropDownStatus = false;
        }
    };

})
```

This code can be simplified further. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: -1 for suggesting `$rootScope` over a service for holding data.

Comment: I am not even sure a service is the right approach. Seems more like a parent controller is needed here. But using `$rootScope` is definitely unadvisable.

Comment: Agreed, a single controller is what I would do as well.